# Russian-built and NATO (USN, European) probe-and-drogue -- are they interoperable?

Tags: military, refueling, tanker

Considering the current diversity of coalition air fleets in some parts of the world (the Horn of Africa situation comes to mind), can Russian-built tankers refuel NATO probe-and-drogue receivers, and vice versa? (Say, a US Navy F/A-18E getting a helping hand from an Indian Air Force Il-78MKI, or an Ethiopian Air Force Su-27 filling its tanks from a Royal Australian Air Force A330 MRTT?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The drogue system was standardized in the 50s and reverse engineered by the USSR in that time so nearly all aircraft that use it are compatible with each other.

Comment: Flying boom does not come into this question at all. The question is whether NATO probe-and-drogue is compatible with Russian-built probe-and-drogue.

Comment: This answer would be a lot clearer if you removed references to the flying boom

Comment: What probe-and-drogue aircraft are *not* compatible with the NATO system?

Answer (score 6):

> Can Russian-built tankers refuel NATO probe-and-drogue receivers, and
>   vice versa?

The Russian system is called UPAZ and its manufacturer Zvezda states

> ***The nozzle assemblies are adapted to the refueling pods of foreign aircraft***

http://777.zvezda-npp.ru/engl/zaprav.html

Basically this means a bog-standard Russian Mig/Sukhoi cannot plug into a Western tanker aircraft without some change in the configuration.

> Say, a US Navy F/A-18E getting a helping hand from an Indian Air Force
>   Il-78MKI

The Indian IL-78s have Israeli-made refuelling equipment so I can't say whether it's compatible with F/A-18E. However, from what I know, India has been using this Israeli equipment to refuel its MiGs and Sukois just fine.